# Cannot run JSF/Primefaces project in Intellij Idea using Glassfish server 5

Tags: intellij-idea, jsf, primefaces, glassfish-5

I am trying to run a JSF/Primefaces project which was working before a couple of jre updates.  Now, I see the following errors being generated and the deployment is stopped:

```
[2021-03-18 05:13:48,685] Artifact Flowchart:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2021-03-18 05:13:50,114] Artifact Flowchart:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2021-03-18 05:13:50,114] Artifact Flowchart:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [Flowchart_war_exploded] : A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/CurveDB
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle
. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I tried to look up those error messages but I couldn't find anything yet.

My JDK is 1.8.0_202 and my JRE is 1.8.0_281.

Can anybody help me figure out the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the mapped JDK in the domain.xml. It is basically saying that it cannot find the content in those classes. It'll be in the first JVM line and this is where you need to verify the glassfish configuration matches.